Error 403 Forbidden when get youtube.members.list, even after right scopes authorization
I am trying to use the endpoint /youtube/v3/members from YoutubeDataAPI, but even after the successful channel authorization with OAuth2, i keep getting the error
(403)   Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.
domain: youtube.com

The authentication scopes that i used were:
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
I get the access_token, but when i call the API (direct in node.js with 'googleapis' youtube.members.list; or with Postman), i still get the 403 error. And yes, the API is enabled in my console.cloud, and my Oauth credential ID is WEB APP.
How can i solve this? Is there any more settings in the channel that needs to be changed?
I followed the documentation from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list, and also asked for help in Gemini-pro-1.5, but no success...
I expect to receive the members list from the channel.

so you read and executed "Reach out to your Google or YouTube representative to request access." from the docs and got permission?

@cyberbrain, actually i did, and the Youtube representative told me i should ask in stackoverflow, and the responsibles for the API would answer.
He told me that is not necessary a permission from him to do this...

Other requests to other parts of the API work properly? I'm neither expert nor responsible for the API, just want to make sure that it is not related to anything with basics of OAuth2.

Sorry for the delay in response, but yes, I used the same access token that I used to call the /members endpoint for other endpoints an it worked successfully. Only with the /members endpoint I receive the error:
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
"domain": "youtube.common",
"reason": "forbidden"
}
]
}

have the same problem, and also be told no necessary permission... need somebody to save me...

I've encountered the same problem and found this
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326362541?pli=1
Seems that it can be request only through a Partner Manager or Google respresentive.
